# How to make one button do two things?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a check button and 3 views, one TextField

I'd like the check button to have the ability to know which view its on,

view1 view1 or view 3. so that when the user types in the right answer the specific actions works for that view its on only!

```
 - (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {



// Enter has been pressed, see if the text in the textView equals our string
NSString *answer = [_textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"q telecom " withString:@""];
// to block user from getting incorrect answer with no text in text field
if([answer isEqualToString:@""]){

}
else

    if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q telecom"]) {


        //Name:Q Telecom - FIRST TEXTFIELD SAVED - This will save the answer (q telecom forever to the user) *SAVED
        NSString *savestring = _textbox.text; NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savedstring"];
        [defaults synchronize];



    // String is correct, resign keyboard, xclear, and protection/shield
    _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    _protectionOutBtn.enabled = NO;
    //Perfect button
    [_closeone setHidden:NO];
    [_wrongone setHidden:YES];

    score = MAX (score +100, 1);
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Σκορ: %d", score]];
   // remeber that coins must always be coins = coins + numeber to add up correctly
   coins = coins +5;
    if(score == 100) {coins = coins + 3;}




    [coinsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins]];


    //coin animation start
    FImageWinfive.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"coindust2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust5.png.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust7.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust8.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust9.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust10.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust11.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"coindust12.png"], nil];

    [FImageWinfive setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    FImageWinfive.animationDuration = 1.5;
    FImageWinfive.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [FImageWinfive startAnimating];
    //coin animation finished
    _textbox.enabled = NO;




}
else {


        CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        [shake setDuration:0.1];
        [shake setRepeatCount:2];
        [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
        [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                             CGPointMake(shaker.center.x - 5,shaker.center.y)]];
        [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                           CGPointMake(shaker.center.x + 5, shaker.center.y)]];
        [shaker.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];


           // Was not correct.  Notify user, or just don't do anything


    [_wrongone setHidden:NO];
    score = score -3;





    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Σκορ: %d", score]];

  //SCORE
}

if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = @"Σωστά!";
     _imageCorP.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxg_25.png"];

} else {
    closeonechange.text = @"Αψογα!";
    _imageCorP.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"telioo.png"];
}
```

Comment: you have check buttons on all three views?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to figure out what view is the superview of the button?

Comment: nope, But Ive named each view differently, like View1, View2, View3, actually the real name of my views are the answers. but I was thinking of making a check button for each but it would get complicated after 35 buttons. I was thinking to call the keyboard to each view! what do you suggest?

Comment: I'd like each view to have a separate answer typed in by using only the one check button!

Comment: first let us know... in each view did u placed the check button?

Comment: He only wants one button @Babul

Comment: No I have a separate view for the check button, which I want to call to a new text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but here's an option.

First, in the `viewController`'s `.m` file, a `@property`:

```
@interface SomeViewController()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITextField *activeField;
@end
```

Now, assume all three of these text fields are delegated by this view controller:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
    self.activeField = textField;
}
```

Now in the method that handles button touch:

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
    if (self.lastActiveField == self.view1) {
        // check view 1
    } else if (self.lastActiveField == self.view2) {
        // check view 2
    } else if (self.lastActiveField == self.view3) {
        // check view 3
    } else {
        // either no field has been selected yet or there are other text fields
        // delegated by this view controller
    }
}
```

---

A slightly better and clearer solution would involve using an `enum` and setting the text field's tags with this `enum`, and then in the `IBAction`, switching on the `enum`.

For example:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ActiveFieldEnum) {
    tag_VIEW1 = 100,
    tag_VIEW2 = 101, 
    tag_VIEW3 = 102
};
```

A property to track the last active button:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) ActiveFieldEnum lastActiveField;
```

Now you can set this in the storyboard or in a life-cycle method of your view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // set up your view

    self.view1.tag = tag_VIEW1;
    self.view2.tag = tag_VIEW2;
    self.view3.tag = tag_VIEW3;
}
```

The text field delegate:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
    self.lastActiveField = textField.tag;
}
```

And now in the button method:

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
    switch(self.lastActiveField) {
        case tag_VIEW1:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case tag_VIEW2:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case tag_VIEW3:
            // do stuff
            break;
        default:
            // same as the final else before
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using the text field, how can I call my custom keyboard to each specific view when needed?

Comment: You can use this exact same method with any `UIView` or `UIView` subclass.  `UITextField`'s `tag` property is by virtue of inheritance from `UIView`.  In order to set the last-active property, your custom view will have to define a protocol and have a delegate in much the same way a `UITextField` does.

Comment: can I make every thing on my view have an enum?

Comment: As I said, the `tag` property comes from `UIView`.  Anything that is a subclass of `UIView` has a `tag` property, and you can give all of these tags unique values (I don't think you can realistically have more unique views than there are unique values in `NSInteger`).